# Can't get nhibernate config section out though configuration manager

Tags: nhibernate, memcached, app-config

I'm trying to to setup Memcached 2nd level caching. I've followed what documentation I could find, including downloading the project from SVN and looking at how it is configured in their test project, and ended up with this in my app.config.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="memcache" type="NHibernate.Caches.MemCache.MemCacheSectionHandler,NHibernate.Caches.MemCache" />
  </configSections>
  <memcache>    
    <memcached host="xx.xx.xx.xx" port="11211" weight="10" />
  </memcache>
</configuration>
```

However, when the MemCache provider code in `NHibernate.Caches.MemCache` calls  `configurationmanager.getsection("memcache")`, null is returned, which causes it to error out.

I have three projects, .UI, .Core, and .Data - the app.config is for .UI and .Data is where `SessionFactory` gets built and the code that wants to load this configuration section is launched. .Data has the `Nhibernate.Caches.Memcache` reference, and I've tried adding it to .UI, however that did not solve the issue.

What is incorrect about this configuration? Or perhaps is it something about my project? Does anyone have any experience at all with `NHibernate.Caches.MemCache`? There is not much information about it to be found via Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being some corruption with my app.config. Everything was right, but it was not being loaded by the assembly. I deleted and re-added it, and then it worked fine.